# Select a specific set of characters in a file using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

In my code I have views defined like below.

```
VIEW Company_Person_Sd IS
   Prompt = 'Company'
   Company.Prompt = 'Company ID'
SELECT company_id                          company_id,
       emp_no                              emp_no,
       Get_Person(company_id, emp_no)      person_id,
       cp.rowid                            objid,
       to_char(cp.rowversion)              objversion,
       rowkey                              objkey
FROM   companies cp;
```

There can be more than one view defined in a single file (usually there are 20 or more).

I want to get the whole view using a regex in python.

I did the same thing to a method like below, using the following regex.(and it worked fine)

```
methodRegex = r"^\s*((FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)\s+(\w+))(.*?)BEGIN(.*?)^END\s*(\w+);"

methodMatches = re.finditer(methodRegex, fContent, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
        
        for methodMatchNum, methodMatch in enumerate(methodMatches, start=1):
            methodContent=methodMatch.group()
            methodNameFull=methodMatch.group(1)
            methodType=methodMatch.group(2)
            methodName=methodMatch.group(3)
```

method example

```
PROCEDURE Prepare___ (
   attr_ IN OUT VARCHAR2 )
IS
  ----
BEGIN
   --
END Prepare___;

PROCEDURE Insert___ (
   attr_ IN OUT VARCHAR2 )
IS
  ----
BEGIN
   --
END Insert___;
```

When I try to do the same for views, it gives the wrong output.
Actually I couldn't find how to catch the end of the view. I tried with semicolon as well, which gave a wrong output.

My regex for views

```
 viewRegex = r"^\s*(VIEW\s+(\w+))(.*?)SELECT(.*?)^FROM\s*(\w+);"
```

Please help me find out where I'm doing it wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of views in a single file, another option is to prevent using `.*?` with `re.DOTALL` to prevent unnecessary backtracking.

Instead, you can match the parts from `VIEW` to `SELECT` to `FROM` checking that what is in between is not another one of the key words to prevent matching too much using a negative lookahead (Assuming these can not occur in between)

For the last part after FROM, you can match word characters, optionally repeated by whitespace chars and again word characters.

```
^(VIEW\s+(\w+))(.*(?:\n(?!SELECT|VIEW|FROM).*)*)\nSELECT\s+(.*(?:\n(?!SELECT|VIEW|FROM).*)*)\nFROM\s+(\w+(?:\s+\w+));
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(VIEW\s+(\w+))` Capture group for VIEW followed by a group for the word characters
- `(.*(?:\n(?!SELECT|VIEW|FROM).*)*)` Capture group matching the rest of the lines, and all lines that do not start with a keyword
- `\nSELECT\s+` Match a newline, SELECT and 1+ whitespace cahrs
- `(.*(?:\n(?!SELECT|VIEW|FROM).*)*)` Capture group matching the rest of the lines, and all lines that do not start with a keyword
- `\nFROM\s+` Match a newline, FROM and 1+whitespace chars
- `(\w+(?:\s+\w+))`; Capture group for the value of FROM, matching 1+ word characters and optionally repeated by whitespace chars and word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/elC7iG/1)

For example (You can omit the `re.VERBOSE` and `re.DOTALL`)

```
import re

methodRegex = r"^^(VIEW\s+(\w+))(.*(?:\n(?!SELECT|VIEW|FROM).*)*)\nSELECT\s+(.*(?:\n(?!SELECT|VIEW|FROM).*)*)\nFROM\s+(\w+(?:\s+\w+));"
fContent = ("VIEW Company_Person_Sd IS\n"
            "   Prompt = 'Company'\n"
            "   Company.Prompt = 'Company ID'\n"
            "SELECT company_id                          company_id,\n"
            "       emp_no                              emp_no,\n"
            "       Get_Person(company_id, emp_no)      person_id,\n"
            "       cp.rowid                            objid,\n"
            "       to_char(cp.rowversion)              objversion,\n"
            "       rowkey                              objkey\n"
            "FROM   companies cp;")
methodMatches = re.finditer(methodRegex, fContent, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for methodMatchNum, methodMatch in enumerate(methodMatches, start=1):
    methodContent = methodMatch.group()
    methodNameFull = methodMatch.group(1)
    methodType = methodMatch.group(2)
    methodName = methodMatch.group(3)
```

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't get any match with `viewRegex` because it only matches when there are only word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) between `FROM` and `;`. Whereas your example also includes a whitespace. So take whitespaces into account as well:

```
viewRegex = r"^\s*(VIEW\s+(\w+))(.*?)SELECT(.*?)^FROM\s*([\w\s]+);"
```